Pytorch error : backward pass RuntimeError: Found dtype Float but expected Double
I have a pytorch model includes GRU layer. I try to multiply the GRU outputs ([16,1])  with a numpy arrary [16,1] which is a Levy stochastic process.
I  get  the error:
"Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass RuntimeError: Found dtype Float but expected Double"

The full error message is:
File "D:\projects\Base Models-v2\pytorchApps\trainer.py", line 33, in train_step
    loss.backward()
  File "C:\Users\Med\anaconda3\envs\ts_adv\Lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py", line 492, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "C:\Users\Med\anaconda3\envs\ts_adv\Lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 251, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: Found dtype Float but expected Double

This error happens when I add this line
out = torch.mul(out, lev)

my code is
class SDE(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, r,m,v,lam,sigma):
        super().__init__()
        self.r = r
        self.m = m
        self.v = v
        self.lam = lam
        self.sigma = sigma

    def forward(self, T, steps, Npaths):
        np.random.seed(4)
        lam = self.lam.detach().numpy()
        sigma= self.sigma.detach().numpy()
        m = self.m.detach().numpy()
        r = self.r.detach().numpy()
        v = self.v.detach().numpy()
        size = (steps, Npaths)
        dt = T / steps
        poi_rv = np.multiply(np.random.poisson(lam * dt, size=size),
                             np.random.normal(m, v, size=size)).cumsum(axis=0)
        geo = np.cumsum(((r - sigma ** 2.0 / 2.0 - lam * (m + v ** 2.0 * 0.5)) * dt +
                         sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(size=size)), axis=0)

        out = np.exp(geo + poi_rv)
        out = out.astype(np.float64)
        print("typeee", type(out[0]))
        return out


class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, args):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
       
      
        self.r = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.02, device = 'cpu'), requires_grad=True) 
        self.m = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.0, device = 'cpu'), requires_grad=True)
        self.v = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.3, device = 'cpu'), requires_grad=True)
        self.lam = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(1.0, device = 'cpu'), requires_grad=True)
        self.sigma = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.2, device = 'cpu'), requires_grad=True)
        self.levy = SDE(self.r,self.m,self.v,self.lam,self.sigma)
        self.args = args
        self.hidden_dim = args.n_hidden_units
        self.input_dim = len(args.features)
        self.output_dim = args.pred_len
        self.layer_dim = args.num_layers
        # GRU layers
        self.gru = nn.GRU(
            self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim, self.layer_dim, batch_first=True, dropout=args.dropout, bidirectional=True)
        # Fully connected layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim * 2, self.output_dim)
        #self.double()

    def forward(self, x):
            #x = x.to(torch.float32)

            lev = self.levy(1.0, 16, 1)
            lev = torch.from_numpy(lev)
            lev= lev.type(torch.DoubleTensor)
            lev = lev.double()
            #lev = torch.tensor(lev)
            #lev = lev.double()


            h0 = torch.zeros(self.args['num_layers']* 2, x.size(0), self.args['n_hidden_units'], device=x.device).requires_grad_()
            out, _ = self.gru(x, h0.detach())
            out = out[:, -1, :]
            out = self.fc(out)

            print(f"before cont out{out.shape} , lev {lev.shape}")
            print(out , lev)

            #out = out * lev
            out = torch.mul(out, lev)
            #out = out.double()

            return out


I tried to add device('cpu') to the parameters, convert lev array to Double, using astype(np.float64), self.double() .... as you can see in the commented lines.
But it doesn't work.
